# Changing value in watching cann`t work in some case with Vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I want to change number to int in watch, but it doesn`t work.

index.vue:

```
<template>
    <test v-model="value" />
</template>
<script>
    import Test from './test.vue';
    export default {
        components: {
            test: Test,
        },
        data() {
            return {
                value: 1,
            };
        },
        watch: {
            value(val) {
                this.value = parseInt(val);
                // this.value = 2;
            }
        }
    };
</script>
```

test.vue:

```
<template>
    <div class="el-input-number">
        <input
        :value="currentValue"
        @input="handleInput"
        ref="input"
        />
    </div>
</template>
<script>

    export default {
        name: 'ElInputNumber',
        props: {
            value: {
                default: 0
            },
        },
        data() {
            return {
                currentValue: 1
            };
        },
        watch: {
            value(value) {
                console.log('value change', value);
                let newVal = Number(value);
                if (isNaN(newVal)) return;
                this.currentValue = newVal;
                this.$emit('input', newVal);
            }
        },
        computed: {
        },
        methods: {
            setCurrentValue(newVal) {
                const oldVal = this.currentValue;
                if (oldVal === newVal) return;
                this.$emit('change', newVal, oldVal);
                this.$emit('input', newVal);
                this.currentValue = newVal;
            },
            handleInput(e) {
                const value = e.target.value;
                const newVal = Number(value);
                if (!isNaN(newVal)) {
                this.setCurrentValue(newVal);
                }
            }
        }
    };
</script>
```

The main code is `this.value = parseInt(val)`.
The initial value is 1. I type 1.1 in input. Then I get changes in watching.
After I set `this.value`, the value watching function isn't called. There is no log.
What's more strange, if I change `this.value = parseInt(val)` to `this.value = 2`, it works once, but the second time I change the value, it doesn`t work.

Code is here: https://github.com/lext-7/vue-watch-component-demo.

Run it, and type 1.1 in that input. You will find that it won't become 1.

Comment: Your code is very confusing... I can't predict at all what would be the behavior of watching the same value in both child and parent, and changing it in both child and parent...

Comment: I can't see why you want to use a watcher here, you should use a computed property for this !

Comment: In the index.vue you are not passing any props to test component, but in your test.vue you added a props property. Why?

Comment: @user7814783 v-model is a shortcut for :value="something" + event binding. So this is probably not the problem.

Comment: @Cobaltway oh yes , forgot that almoost, got too much used to short hand ":". Thanks for correcting

Comment: In your case `watch` fires on each `value` change if it's assigned a non-integer value: https://jsfiddle.net/wostex/63t082p2/60/ (click 1.1 several times and look into console)

Comment: your input is bound to `currentValue` not `value`, so changing the value in the input won't trigger the `value` watcher.

Comment: @soju Although I can use compoted property, but why it doesn't work?

Comment: @thanksd I change the value, which is wacthed is test.vue. In the watch function, I set the currentValue to newVal.

Comment: @lext it does set for a moment, but you immediately assign a new value in the listener and `watch` fires again. What are you trying to achieve? This approach looks like a duct tape.

Comment: @wostex  I have tried this, but if I make it into component, it doesn't work.

Comment: @lext what's your goal with this code? I believe there's better solution.

Comment: @wostex I just want to make the input value to be an interger. So I parseInt the value in watch function. The input component isn't native. It's a component working like an input.

Comment: @lext check this code: https://jsfiddle.net/wostex/63t082p2/61/

Comment: @wostex https://github.com/lext-7/vue-watch-component-demo you can run this code. You type 1.1 to that input.

Comment: @lext If you simply are trying to cast the input as a number, use [`v-model.number`](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#number)